# Construct a new map using List of Maps using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I converted below json data (in example) to List<Map<String, String>> and from that i want to construct a new Map using Java 8 streams and the output should look like below. could someone help me with this?

```
Key         value
Service1: DEACTIVATED
Service2: ACTIVATED
Service3: DEACTIVATED
```

Ex:

```
[
{
 name=Service1, 
 desiredState=DEACTIVATED
}, 
{
 name=Service2, 
 desiredState=ACTIVATED
}, 
{
  name=Service3, 
  desiredState=DEACTIVATED
}
]
```

Comment: Question is not clear, please edit.

Comment: Am not sure which part is unclear but i edited little bit

Comment: Hi! I agree with @Frighi, can you provide what do you have as an input and what have you done already? For example, your JSON could be already parsed & in memory or it can be still in the file / network buffer / etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it well, you need to merge your maps in a way such that the value of the `name` key is the key that maps to the value of the `desiredState` key. You could do it this way:

```
Map<String, String> result = listOfMaps.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             m -> m.get("name"),
             m -> m.get("desiredState"),
             (o, n) -> n));
```

This assumes that all maps from the list have `name` and `desiredState` entries. The `(o, n) -> n` merge function must be provided, in case there are collisions when creating the `result` map (i.e. entries with the same key). Here, between old and new values, I've chosen the new value.

Answer (score 2):

From what I could comprehend, you aim to convert List<Map<String,String>> to Map<String,String>.

```
 List<Map<String,String>> myMap = .... // map which you have already.
    
    Map<String,String> resultMap = myMap.stream()
                                   .flatMap(map ->  map.entrySet().stream())  // Get a flatMap of the entryset. This will form a stream of Map.Entry
                                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), (k1, k2) -> k2));
```

Here (k1,k2) -> k2 is a merge function in case if there are multiple entries for same keys while constructing the resultMap.